# Trouble using json-path in camel blueprint test

Tags: unit-testing, apache-camel, jsonpath, blueprint-osgi

I am trying to test a Camel Blueprint route. I am using camel version 2.12 and camel-jsonpath is available as of version 2.13. So instead of camel-jsonpath, I am trying to use
json-path itself in my unit tests. But as soon as adding the json-path dependency, my unit tests are failing.
This is the dependency ;

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
  <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

My test class extends from CamelBlueprintTestSupport and after adding this dependency I got the following exception;

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Gave up waiting for service (objectClass=org.apache.camel.CamelContext)
```

Comment: Have you installed all the json-path JARs in the Karaf container? eg take a look at camel-jsonpath feature from that release and see which JARs/bundles it has listed and then you install those manually yourself